# Listbox.items.Add adds by value of 2 Fields

Tags: c#, .net

Im adding an item to a listbox, and the item has two fields that the `.Add` for some reason sorts by them as even using `.Sort` after returns the same results.

I've tried sorting it after using the default sorter and overrided compare in a FileComparer, using a linq query also returns the same.

```
// override for ProductFile ToString() _linkedProducts, _VisibleCount are both Int 
public override string ToString()
{
    return (_linkedProducts > -1 ? 
           "(" + _linkedProducts + ")" 
            + (_visibleCount == _linkedProducts ? "   " : "(H)") + "\t" 
            : "") + _name;
}

// when nothing is searched to slowly load items 
// (noone scrolls so its ok that this is slow)     
foreach (ProductFile file in _files)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
    {
        lock (target) { target.Items.Add(file); }
    }));
    //addProgress();
}

// used when searching    
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
{
    target.Items.AddRange(
        (from c in _files
        where c.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(searchStr[0].ToLower())
        select c).OrderBy(td => td.Name).ToArray()
    );
}));
```

Expected is a list in alphabetic order, but what I get instead is that the list gets divided into groups based on the value of _linkedProducts and _VisibleCount in alphabetic order.

This code is used in a function called to filter 2 seperate listboxes one of witch works as intended the other returning what I described above code for starting the filterProcess is the same used in the same types of events.

Comment: I get needing to write a good question, but noone even tried to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer so if anyone is having problems with your listbox being sorted by fields of your item when you don't want its the property `Sorted` of the listbox being set to true.